# EF7 Injecting Model Configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I inject model configuration to the dbcontext on the startup.cs or using a factory pattern.

Comment: Did you manage this?

Comment: so far no, I created an issue in GibHub see response here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2754